# Please anybody could tell me that how we can filter the data on the base of single date by a plane query

Tags: c#, datagridview, filtering

```
string query = "Select * from tbl_Items where PurchaseDate=" + dateTimePicker1.Value;
dataGridView1.DataSource = DataAccessLayer.ExecuteTable(query);
```

Above code is generating error that **Incorrect syntax near '6'.**. I have tried many time but not get result.if I gave it static date like that (**'2019-01-01'** instead of **datetimepicker** value) it show the result correct.so Please anyone have an idea then please.

Comment: Do not glue data into strings to make SQL - use Parameters and the problem will go away

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Comment: You are missing string delimiter on date provided by DateTimePicker; you must also look at the query string using debug to look at the final query string you send to DataAccessLayer class.

Answer (score -1):

You miss an *apostrophe* or *sql delimiter* during building `Sql` code, try the following code :

```
string query = "Select * from tbl_Items where PurchaseDate='" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "'";
```

i hope this will help you fix the issue

Comment: @Learner, if the solution not work, please leave a comment.

Comment: @Learner you're welcome! i answered to that a year ago :D